# WP7 crop text area from image

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-7

I need to crop an image such that it contains only text, no blank area..
eg. below..

> Like this image contains a lot of space on all the four sides

[image: with space]

> and this one is the cropped version of the image.

[image: without space]

is there something (library) that can automate this process.